# respond_to UnknownFormat

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ajax

show.html.erb file:

```
<%= button_to "1w", installation_path, params: { type: "graph", time: "week" },  :class => "button", :method => :get %>
```

show.js.erb file:

```
$("#main-graph").html("<%= escape_javascript(render :partial => 'graphs/consumptionsChart',  :locals => {installation_id: @id_ins}) %>");
```

controller:

```
  def show
    if params[:type] == "graph"
      @id_ins = "80"
      respond_to do |format|
        format.js
      end
    end 
  end
```

When I click in a button "1w" I receive the error "ActionController::UnknownFormat" in the line of "respond_to do |format|".

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
<%= button_to "1w", installation_path(:format => "js"), params: { type: "graph", time: "week" },  :class => "button", :method => :get %>
```